# Setect AJAX Request in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

OK, this has taken me 3 days and i am no further on than when i started.

i am building a web app at the request of my employer. the APP requires communication with a server which uses PHP Code.

I am currently trying to get my PHP code to detect whether a request is AJAX or not. the response i am getting suggests to me that i have done something wrong.

I used the code that was marked as an answer to another question so i'm not sure what's wrong :/

This is the PHP code: - the response from the server is `No GET or PUT request found`

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
include_once("xmlHandler.php");

function s($message){
echo $message. "<br>";
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')) {
    echo "GET has been received";
}else{
    s("No GET or PUT request found");
}

?>
```

the AJAX request looks like this:

```
var data = {
  "data" : "test"
};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://www.qsl.org.uk/apps/main.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);

    alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
  }
});
```

any help here would be greatly appreciated as i am quite inexperienced with PHP and have no idea what i've done wrong

Comment: for some reason the headers of my php file won't appear in the published post 0.o

Comment: _"I am currently trying to get my PHP code to detect whether a request is AJAX or not"_ --> send `data : { "isAjax" : "true" }` :)

Comment: when you are using dataType: "json" than no need to use ContentType: "application/json", and bascially this application/json works for php you must use in your php header("Content-type:application/json");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just pass an additional variable along with the ajax request that indicates that it was an ajax request;

```
var data = {
  "data": "test",
  "ajax": true
};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://www.qsl.org.uk/apps/main.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);

    alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
  }
});
```

Then you can retrieve that in PHP;

`$_GET['ajax']`

Comment: i won't lie, i am very dissapointed that it was this easy -_- Why did i not think of this? 0.o... thanks :)

Comment: I do not understand still why you added "ajax": true

Comment: @SpringLearner as supposed to what?

Comment: @Novocaine OP was using `var data = {
  "data" : "test"
};` and you added `"ajax": true` to make `var data = {
  "data": "test",
  "ajax": true
};` I want to know the reason

Comment: ajax:true means my server-side code won't run without an ajax request, with ajax:true (i think) i can be sure the server will only run when it get's a request from the app (as opposed to typing a link directly into the address bar)

Comment: @SpringLearner it's just so that the PHP script can distinguish between the ajax request and any other request. Adding in `"ajax": true` as another variable sent with the request lets the script know that it is indeed requested via this ajax request.

Comment: @Novocaine I am basically a java developer and I have not seen this type of scenario.